# Changing inputType of Ext.form.TextField does not affect immediately

Tags: events, extjs

In my program, I want to change the inputType of Ext.form.TextField when clicking another control. You an imagine about the password textfield and a "Show/Hide" button. I register event for the "Show/Hide" button to change the display form of password. But because that textfield has already rendered before this button click event was fired, so the inputType of it dis not affect immediately. Can you help me? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The config options are not properties in the sense of C# for example, changing them does nothing because there's no way for the object to know you've changed them, which is usually why you have the many set* methods.

However there is no method for this for TextField so you'll probably have to re-create the object with the required configuration.